# Reading and writing using system calls

Tags: c

I have to use read a file and write the information to another file using system call. I have opened the file for reading as below
    `filedesc =  open(argv[1],O_RDONLY); //which works fine` 
opened a file to write as below: 
    `fdw=creat(strcat(store,argv[1]),PERMS) // PERMS 0666`
Used lseek to reach to the one of file filedesc ( to reverse and print )

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<fcntl.h>
 #include<sys/stat.h>
 #include<unistd.h>
 #include<sys/types.h>
 #include<string.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv [ ])
  {

     int filedesc,n,i,fdw,pos;
     char c;
     const char * prefix = "reserve_";
     int needed = strlen( argv[ 1 ] ) + strlen( prefix ) + 1;
     char store[ needed ];
     strcpy( store, prefix );

     if(argc != 2)
   {
       printf(" usage : %s filename ", argv[0]);
     }

         //strcat( store, argv[ 1 ] );
         //printf( "%s\n", store );


      filedesc =  open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
         if(filedesc <1 )
            {  printf("Unable to open file\n");
          exit(1); }


     if((fdw=creat(strcat(store,argv[1]),PERMS))==-1)
      printf("Unable to create file,please use perror to find details\n");
    else printf("File created\n");



       if((pos=lseek(filedesc,0,SEEK_END))==0)
         {
           printf("Empty file\n");
            exit(-1);
           }
         i=pos-1; 
             //printf("%d",i);

            while(i!=0)
             {
             pos=lseek(filedesc,i-1,SEEK_SET);
              read(filedesc,&c,1);
              if( write(fdw,&c,1)!=1)  //information is not being written to the file
                printf("Error\n");     //pointed by fdw rather getting printed on the
                                       //screen
                i--;                     
            }

        close(filedesc);
          close(fdw);



            }
```

Problem: If i am running this without first argument, it gives a segmentation fault instead of the usage. Please help

Comment: edited the previous post and included the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` line is wrong. It will actually **store the result of the comparison** in `fdw` instead of storing the result of `creat(2)`.

```
if(fdw=creat(strcat(store,argv[1]),PERMS)==-1) /* Wrong. */
```

Try:

```
if((fdw = creat(strcat(store, argv[1]), PERMS)) == -1)
   ^                                          ^
```

#### EDIT

You should also check the result of `read`:

```
if (read(filedesc, &c, 1) <= 0)
    break;
```

Comment: Great suggestion.. This worked.. Thank you so much... There is one more issue that is coming up. The new file being created has an extra new line character which is not there in the input file. How can i remove that ?

Comment: @cinicutar: Thanks for the suggestion but still the same issue. The o/p file has a new line followed by olleh. Is there way to chomp off this new line being read .

Comment: the input file contains the string 'hello' which this programs reverses . So its prints a new line and then the reversed string into the file. Need to eliminate the new line char

Comment: @Faizan Start from `i=pos - 1`.

Comment: got it.. works now.. thank you once again.. only 1 hour left for assignment submission:) was bout to loose hope..thanks again

Comment: Hi everyone.. if I run this program without the first argument instead of usage it now gives segmentation fault. Any suggestions please

Comment: @Faizan `if (argc < 2) exit(1);`.

Comment: I made this change but it still gives segmenatation fault. I want it to usage : argv[0] filename

Comment: @Faizan Ask another question.